# NRI returnig to india for good but have forex income in USA

Tags: united-states, income-tax, india

I worked in US for 4 years and decided to return to india for good . I have regular income from forex which comes to US bank account and I pay tax to US government. Once I return to India , am planning to continue paying tax to US government for my forex profit income if any and transfer the profit money to NRE account in India. PLease let me know if I have to pay tax in india as well for this money transferred.

Regards,
Shree

Comment: Unless you specify what the foreign country is that is generating "profits" for you in a foreign currency and transferring the profits to your US bank account, it is kind of hard to even start on an answer to your question.

Comment: As Indian resident you can't hold NRE account. You need to close the account